# Unable to subset within mutate() following a summarize() with a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, tibble

I don't know if this is behavior unique to handling `tibbles`, and that I need to subset it a different way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)
df <- gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>% 
  summarize(avg_life = mean(lifeExp))
```

This produces a tibble, `df`.

```
# A tibble: 60 x 3
# Groups:   year [?]
    year continent avg_life
   <int> <fct>        <dbl>
 1  1952 Africa        39.1
 2  1952 Americas      53.3
 3  1952 Asia          46.3
 4  1952 Europe        64.4
 5  1952 Oceania       69.3
 6  1957 Africa        41.3
 7  1957 Americas      56.0
 8  1957 Asia          49.3
 9  1957 Europe        66.7
10  1957 Oceania       70.3
# ... with 50 more rows
```

I thought the next step would work, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956486/easier-way-to-calculate-change-in-variable-using-dplyr) suggests it should.

If I subset it the standard way, it produces the expected output.

```
df$avg_life[df$year == 1952]
[1] 39.13550 53.27984 46.31439 64.40850 69.25500
```

If I try to do it within a `mutate()`, it yields nothing.

```
df <- gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>% 
  summarize(avg_life = mean(lifeExp)) %>% 
  mutate(life_chg = avg_life - avg_life[year == 1952])
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `life_chg` must be length 5 (the group size) or one, not 0

Changing the `==` to `>` produces all `0`, but it at least works, letting me know everything is declared.

Manually passing what should give me the output desired, also produces all `0`.

```
df <- gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>% 
  summarize(avg_life = mean(lifeExp)) %>% 
  mutate(life_chg = avg_life - avg_life[c(T, T, T, T, T, rep(F, 55))])
```

Why does this not work within a `mutate()` here, and how do you do this correctly? I imagine it has something to do with grouping and creating variables, but I can't seem to find out why.

The structure of df:

```
str(df)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 60 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ year     : int  1952 1952 1952 1952 1952 1957 1957 1957 1957 1957 ...
 $ continent: Factor w/ 5 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ avg_life : num  39.1 53.3 46.3 64.4 69.3 ...
 $ life_chg : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr "year"
 - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':  12 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ year: int  1952 1957 1962 1967 1972 1977 1982 1987 1992 1997 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "year"
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "indices")=List of 12
  ..$ : int  0 1 2 3 4
  ..$ : int  5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ : int  10 11 12 13 14
  ..$ : int  15 16 17 18 19
  ..$ : int  20 21 22 23 24
  ..$ : int  25 26 27 28 29
  ..$ : int  30 31 32 33 34
  ..$ : int  35 36 37 38 39
  ..$ : int  40 41 42 43 44
  ..$ : int  45 46 47 48 49
  ..$ : int  50 51 52 53 54
  ..$ : int  55 56 57 58 59
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 5
```

Comment: The tibble is still grouped by year when you call `mutate`. Try ungrouping it first. Oh and probably `year` should not be in quotes...?

Comment: Wow, that was an easy fix. Thank you. I tried both without and with, same result. Ungrouping worked.

Comment: Still get an error with `summarize(avg_life = mean(lifeExp)) %>% 
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(...)`. Did I miss something?

Comment: With quotes around `year` produces an error, need to remove them as well.

Comment: Rigth, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by `joran`, you have to `ungroup` first.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>%
  summarize(avg_life = mean(lifeExp)) %>%
  ungroup(.) %>%
  mutate(life_chg = avg_life - avg_life[year == 1952])

# A tibble: 60 x 4
    year continent avg_life life_chg
   <int> <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1952 Africa        39.1     0   
 2  1952 Americas      53.3     0   
 3  1952 Asia          46.3     0   
 4  1952 Europe        64.4     0   
 5  1952 Oceania       69.3     0   
 6  1957 Africa        41.3     2.13
 7  1957 Americas      56.0     2.68
 8  1957 Asia          49.3     3.00
 9  1957 Europe        66.7     2.29
10  1957 Oceania       70.3     1.04
# ... with 50 more rows
```